# How to insert two lists in a terminal?

Tags: python, list, shell, terminal

I want to do this exercise which I have done well with the following code but I want to do it with the second code but I don't know how to introduce two lists in a Terminal:

**Exercise: Create a function that receives two input parameters of type list and that returns a list where the two lists are combined, alternately.**

```
import sys

a = ["x","y","z"]
b = [1,2,3]

def example(a, b):

    array = []

    lena = len(a)
    lenb = len(b)

    if lena > lenb:
        control = lena
    else:
        control = lenb


    for i in range (control):
        if i < lena:
            array.append(a[i])
        if i < lenb:
            array.append(b[i])

    return c

print(example(a, b))
```

This is the way I have to do:

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1:]
b = list(map(int, sys.argv[1:]))

def example(a, b):

    array = []

    lena = len(a)
    lenb = len(b)

    if lena > lenb:
        control = lena
    else:
        control = lenb


    for i in range (control):
        if i < lena:
            array.append(a[i])
        if i < lenb:
            array.append(b[i])

    return c

print(example(a, b))
```

Comment: read elements as strings (e.g., `1,2,3`) and use `split(',')` on them which will produce `['1', '2', '3']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--list1', nargs='*', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--list2', nargs='*', required=True)

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
print(args['list1'])
print(args['list2'])
```

Usage:

`python module_name.py --list1 x y z --list2 1 2 3`

`['x', 'y', 'z']`

`['1', '2', '3']`

**UPDATE**

I've noticed your comment for the previous answer. If you want to distinguish between strings and numbers you can do as following:

```
import sys
import json
lists_str = '[' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]).replace('] [', '],[') + ']'
lists = json.loads(lists_str)
print(lists[0])
print(lists[1])
```

So now your input should be of form:

`python module_name.py  [\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"] [1, 2, 3, \"a\"]`

and you will get:

`['a', 'b', 'c']`

`[1, 2, 3, 'a']`

Note that now your input lists can be of mixed types.

Comment: Your update is what I'm searching but why do I have to write the slashs  in the input? I want this to be my input: python module_name.py  ["a", "b", "c"] [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Terminal input uses double quotes as boundaries for an argument (everything between is treated as single thing). It is a special character. So if you want to include such special characters in your input string you have to use slashes. More info on this:https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes

Comment: @smxrlxp do you always have that one of your lists contains alphabet characters and the other numbers? If so it’s not a problem. Otherwise, you can’t distinct between ‘5’ and 5 without backslash+quotes.

Comment: In this exercise yes, now I understand, thanks you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1].split(",")
b = sys.argv[2].split(",")

a.extend(b)  # Depends on what you understand as "combine"
print(a)
```

In your current code you are probably passing each list item as a serperate argument. To pass two lists you need to quote each list like `foo.py "1, 2, 3" "a, b, c"`.

Outputs: `['1', ' 2', ' 3', 'a', ' b', ' c']`.

Comment: Well, this way work if I don't use an integer variable "b = list(map(int, sys.argv[1:]))" so this isn't what I'm searching.

Comment: @smxrlxp If you want `a` or `b` to be an integer list you can just convert the list.